# My Strapi project was working fine on Heroku, I pushed some changes and now it gives me H10 error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, deployment, strapi

I am facing a very weird error.

I deployed my Strapi application on Heroku on June 18 and it worked perfectly fine.

Now after 19 days, I made some changes to my app and pushed it to Heroku again, but it started giving the h10 error.

The error is something like:

```
2021-07-07T15:22:28.510738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-07-07T15:22:28.510819+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-07-07T15_22_28_486Z-debug.log
2021-07-07T15:22:28.610051+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-07T15:22:28.715261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-07T15:22:29.185674+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=oncore-project-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=f60afffe-f974-4512-8129-ab45f1f45724 fwd="119.160.97.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-07T15:22:35.505269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=oncore-project-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=cf7d35af-1539-4cb7-8405-1e2a8c8c23f5 fwd="119.160.97.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The tricky part is that I did not change any configuration these days. I just worked inside the Strapi and added some content types and edited the existing content types.

My Production database.js file looks like this:

```
const { parse } = require("pg-connection-string");

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  const { host, port, database, user, password } = parse(env("DATABASE_URL"));

  return {
    defaultConnection: "default",
    connections: {
      default: {
        connector: "bookshelf",
        settings: {
          client: "postgres",
          host,
          port,
          database,
          username: user,
          password,
          ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
          },
        },
        options: {
          ssl: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```

And it resides on ./config/env/production/database.js

And my production level server.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  url: env("HEROKU_URL"),
});
```

And it resides on ./config/env/production/server.js.

I have also read the related questions on the Strapi Forum and Github repo. Most of those solutions say that I need to change the database.js file for SSL changes. And Heroku rolled these changes in March 2021. but my application was working with this config setting on June 18.

By the way, I have also tried those settings but it didn’t work for me.

Please help me to solve this problem.

P.S: I bootstrapped my strapi project from this repo: GitHub - strapi/strapi-starter-next-blog: Strapi Starter Next Blog

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that my app was being crashed NOT because of SSL.

My database.js and server.js files were configured correctly.

The mistake I was making was that I added some new collections types and also made some fields “required”.

When I pushed these changes to the Heroku, the existing Heroku Postgres database did not have values for these required fields. Postgres was returning the NULL values for the new fields. So, this was creating the issue.

Another important thing is that always have Heroku CLI installed. I was just relying on the Heroku dashboard logs and it doesn’t provide the detailed logs.

When I installed the Heroku CLI and run the command for logs, I found this error log:

```
2021-07-07T18:01:06.214885+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-07T18:01:06.214Z] error error: alter table "writers" add column "slug" varchar(255) not null, add column "title" varchar(255) not null, add column "description" text not null - column "slug" of relation "writers" contains null values
```

How I was able to solve this issue?

I made those fields NOT required in the local development and then pushed the changes. After that, I added values for those fields on the Heroku instance of my app. And then I mark the fields as “required” in the local development. And then pushed changes again to Heroku.

I am not sure whether this correct way of solving the problem or just a workaround BUT this is what worked for me.

Thanks.